# implementing Google Vision API in my application

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I need an AI model for image searching. what I intend to do is that when an image of a person is passed to the model. The model should be able to search and return all images of that same person already stored in my system.  I would like to know if I can implement this using google vision API. Your feedback is appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Did you try some models already, can you show us what you tried so far?

Comment: How do you expect to detect the same person? Even if they changed clothes? Do you want to maybe just detect faces? https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-faces